# Windows 10 performance issues without SSD disk

Tags: windows-10

I manage a Windows domain and over the years I noticed our Windows 10 computers are becoming slower and slower due to disk bandwidth saturation.

I heard about many people that frustrated by poor performance switched to **ssd** disk and then lived happy, so the bottleneck seems to be the disk.

I would like to understand better the cause of this increase in disk utilization: the applications we use are the same of years ago, Adobe Reader, Microsoft Office, the antivirus, ecc. These applications are updated regularly, we switched to Microsoft 365 and Teams which may need more resources, the anti-virus is expected to do deeper checks than before, I take these factors into account, but opening task manager it is common to find  100% disk utilization for minutes, and in the meantime the computer is almost unresponsive.

I suspect that after some feature update under the hood Windows is now doing some new activities reading and writing large quantities of data. I'm looking for some sort of survive guide for disabling all the disk consuming services we don't really need.

Comment: Use the resource monitor to see what processes use disk IO. To make sure: The second half of your question refers to a system with HDD or SSD?

Comment: We experience disk saturation with HDD disks, we have a few computers with SSD and they don't get stuck if they don't have heavy computations. Resource monitor doesn't show  an unique cause, most of the time it is the anti-virus or some mysterious (for me) windows process, anyway after minutes the disk utilization returns and stays to normal for some hours. As stated before I would need a sort of survive guide, I think I have to disable all non essential services in order to save disk bandwidth.

Comment: If a HDD blocks for several seconds this doesn't have to be the disc utilization. If the HDD is a consumer on (not a server HDD) to my experience this means the HDD has bad blocks and is stuck in recovering data. This can take up to several minutes and is shown as 100% utilization. Check the HDD SMART values and if it has bad sectors replace the HDD.

Comment: Modern OSes **expect** to be run from SSD. They don't optimise disk operations in the same way as they used to, because they don't need to. Instead they optimise RAM utilisation. If you have low RAM *and* HD, that's going to be horribly slow these days.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm, until recently I was using Windows 7 on my computers, and had refused to upgrade (even for free) to Windows 10 with this major performance issue. On all computer I upgraded to Windows 10, performance are awful both at startup and even running it, even though these are mainly Intel i7/16GB/high end HDD (e.g. 6To Hitachi). My conclusion: upgrade the computers with SSD...
(or keep the computer to run Windows 7 or other OS like Linux)
Microsoft noticed that with SSD they could do bloaterware to replace their bloatware OS, and making people replace their computer means making people buy new licenses! Why would they do something that would prevent them to get more benefits?
[image]

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1159927)

Comment: This does somehow answer the question by saying there is magic solution with Windows 10 as it is a hardcoded regression in comparison to previous releases. Some Windows 10 potential fix/workarounds are listed on EaseUS website: https://www.easeus.com/resource/how-to-lower-disk-usage-in-windows-10.html but I doubt of any significant improvement, while these could bring unwanted side effects like disabling Windows search...